# It works to (+, -, *) but can not divide. Can somebody help me?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to divide with echo but it is not working. Can somebody help me?

```
<body>
    <div id = 'sonuc'> Gönderilen değerlere göre bu div 'in içeriği değişecek</div>

<input type = "text" name = "kullanici" id = "kullanici_id"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "sifre" id = "sifre_id"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "sifre" id = "karton_gr"/>
    <input type = "button" name = "gonder" id = "gonder" value = "Gönder"/>

    <script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#gonder").click(function() {
            var kullanici_degeri = $('#kullanici_id').val();
            var sifre_degeri = $('#sifre_id').val();
            var karton_degeri = $('#karton_gr').val();

            $.post("ornek2.php", {
                    kullanici_gonder: kullanici_degeri,
                    sifre_gonder: sifre_degeri,
                    karton_gonder: karton_degeri
                }

                ,
                function(gonderVeri) {
                    $('#sonuc').html(gonderVeri);

                });
        });
    });

</script> <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is echo but there is nothing wrong with syntax when i validate. Do someone knows where I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
<?php
$gelen_kullanici = $_POST['kullanici_gonder'];
$gelen_sifre = $_POST['sifre_gonder'];
$karton_gonder=$_POST['karton_gonder'];

echo "($gelen_kullanici / $gelen_sifre) * $karton_gonder";
?>
```

Comment: All your doing is building a string with the various fields filled in, this won't do any maths on the fields.

Comment: Try to typecast the all posted data into int values and remove those double quotes in echo statement.

Comment: What is your result? And what you've expected?

Comment: You should do like: `echo ($gelen_kullanici / $gelen_sifre) * $karton_gonder`. Without quotes.

Comment: Do not use variable inside quotes. If so then it will be validated as string not variable. Example 
echo ($gelen_kullanici / $gelen_sifre) * $karton_gonder;

Comment: You would probably be better to change the HTML to specify the fields type "number" if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Try below snippet:

```
<?php
$gelen_kullanici = (int)$_POST['kullanici_gonder'];
$gelen_sifre = (int)$_POST['sifre_gonder'];
$karton_gonder=(int)$_POST['karton_gonder'];

echo ($gelen_kullanici/$gelen_sifre)*$karton_gonder;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, without double quotes

```
echo ($gelen_kullanici / $gelen_sifre) * $karton_gonder;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Quote ("), anything inside it will act as a "String". Remove the Quote (") from the echo. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong, you should not use " " Quote for Arithmetic operation variable display.

Use This Code

```
<?php
$gelen_kullanici = $_POST['kullanici_gonder'];
$gelen_sifre = $_POST['sifre_gonder'];
$karton_gonder=$_POST['karton_gonder'];

echo ($gelen_kullanici / $gelen_sifre) * $karton_gonder;
?>
```